# Facebook app - Where to start?

Tags: facebook

I have read many articles about facebook apps, but I can't find anything what I need. Is it possible to create an App for Facebook with HTML/ CSS / Jquery without to using FBML and load this app from my server? Is it possible to use in this app the facebook functions like share, add app to my account etc? Is there any doku or example apps, where I can take a look?

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What delayed my app getting to work was realizing that the canvas URL request is HTTP POST - not HTTP GET as otherwise usual. A simple way to start is looking at example apps that have their source code open. There're examples both for PHP and python at the developer pages. A good example of a simple facebook app that uses google app engine is [runwithfriends](http://runwithfriends.appspot.com)

Answer (score 0):

FBML is in the process of deprecation in favor of the [Graph Api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for quite a while now.
Excerpt from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/:

> We are in the process of deprecating FBML. If you are building a new application on Facebook.com, please implement your application using HTML, JavaScript and CSS. You can use our JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins to embedded many of the same social features available in FBML. While there is still functionality that we have not ported over yet, we are no longer adding new features to FBML.

The Graph Api is easily accessible through JavaScript.

For a quick start you can use [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/) as a start.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, fbml is not supported anymore. so forget about that.
You can write your fb app in many languages, for example you can do it in Ruby on Rails, PHP, or C#/ASP.NET etc, whatever you prefer (although you might want to look if there are some frameworks available for your platform, for using facebook. will make your life easier).

Then, setup your app from facebook developer to match your ip, and you're set to go